# VueJs - Blank page when creating a new untouched project

Tags: nginx, webpack, vuejs2

I've installed a version of VueJS on a Digitalocean server but all I keep seeing is a blank page. This is just a plain, stock project created using the Vue CLI.

Have no idea what the issue can be.

Here's what I have in my sites-available for Nginx. It's the only thing I've changed. Everything else for this Vue project is completely stock.

```html
server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server;

 root /var/www/midtest/public;

 index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

 server_name _;

 error_page 404 /index.html;

 location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }
}
```

Comment: Nothing in the console? Did you check that the JS code is loaded on your page?